# Merge two tables with no relation on columns

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to merge two tables that has no relations on columns.

This are the examples:

Table A:

[image]

Table B:

[image]

The idea is to merge the tables, creating a row for each row that are in both tables, and assigning 'NA' to the column that we don't have information.
This would be the result example:

[image]

I have tried with **merge()** but in this case I just get one row (with the values) instead of two.

The idea is to merge two tables with a lot of columns and a lot of rows, how can I do this?

Comment: Are these `data.frame`s?  What if there are more number of rows?

Comment: are more rows. I have editted  the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rbind.fill()` from `plyr` should also work fine. It combines data frames by row, filling missing columns with `NA`. Try out:

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(df1, df2)
  Gender Age ID Group
1      0  27 NA    NA
2     NA  NA  1     0
```

In case you have matrices, use `rbind.fill.matrix()`

Answer (score 2):

```
df.1[, colnames(df.2)] <- NA
df.2[, colnames(df.1)[1:2]] <- NA

rbind(df.1, df.2)
```

> ```
>   Gender Age Id Group
> 1      0  27 NA    NA
> 2     NA  NA  1     0
> ```

### Sample data

```
df.1 <- data.frame(Gender = 0, Age = 27)
df.2 <- data.frame(Id = 1, Group = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done more easily with `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(A, B)
#   Gender Age id Group
#1      0  27 NA    NA
#2     NA  NA  1     0
```

#### data

```
A <- data.frame(Gender = 0, Age =27)
B <- data.frame(id = 1, Group = 0)
```